# Pandas Dataframe_to_csv columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to read a csv file, that has no headers and 2 columns,

```
inp = pd.read_csv('csvfile')
```

alter some of its values and save it back to a csv in the same format.

```
inp.to_csv('csvfile_new')
```

Unfortunately the file is saved in only one big column. Is there a way to keep 2 columns?

Comment: Please post your full code and a sample of the CSV output.

Comment: Does your input file actually contain comma separated values? I suspect not and that it is being read in as one column instead of 2. Look into the `sep` parameter of `read_csv`.

Comment: Most likely you have whitespace or some other delimiter, which can be accounted for by `sep` / `delimiter` / `delim_whitespace` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the context of your data, but if it is not delimited by commas, try to do this

```
inp = pd.read_csv('csvfile', delim_whitespace=True)
```

then

```
inp.to_csv('csvfile_new', sep=' ')
```